# Git Clone from SSH Repository

Tags: git, git-svn

I used to be able to clone from my personal git repository but now i seem to be running into an error.

```
user:dev.site.com mikesilvis$ git clone { my ssh directory }
server@ipaddress's password: 

remote: Counting objects: 3622, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2718/2718), done.
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.  
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

It seems to be working however while I push files to the repository.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just making a new remote repository on the server and re pushing all of my local information to it.

still have not found an answer to my problem though.

Answer (score 0):

If push is working, you can try to imitate that [GitHub issue](http://support.github.com/discussions/repos/107-aborting-due-to-possible-repository-corruption-on-the-remote-side) and do a:

```
git push origin --all
```

, and see if that solves the cloning problem.

Comment: VonC, I actually found this and tried it. It did not work. It is worth noting that I do NOT use GitHub's servers to host my repository.

Comment: @Mike: I thought you didn't use GitHub ;) But still, I hoped a `push --all` would somehow the remote repo. Other than that, you still have to check for issues on resources (memory, disk space, ...) on the remote and/or the client.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to fix git clone, however, if you need those files cloned you can save a local copy of the repository and clone from that.

e.g. I have myrepo.git on a user git and when I git clone git@localhost:myrepo.git I get that error

```
cp /home/git/repositories/myrepo.git ~
git clone ~/myrepo.git
rm -rf ~/myrepo.git
```

and you should have a myrepo folder with the files you need